# How can I find out what part of a Stored Procedure is giving me an error?

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_purchase_test
    @AdminTestId int,
    @PurchaseDate DATETIME OUTPUT,
    @RC     INT OUTPUT,
    @UserId INT   
AS

BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @UserTestId INT;

        INSERT INTO dbo.UserTest
        (  
            AdminTestId,
            PurchaseDate,
            UserId,
            Sequence               
        ) 
        SELECT  AdminTestId,
                @PurchaseDate,
                @UserId,
                1
        FROM    AdminTest
        WHERE   AdminTestId = @AdminTestId 

        SET @UserTestId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO dbo.UserTestQuestion
        (  
            UserTestId,      
            QuestionNumber,  
            QuestionUId,               
            UserId                    
        ) 
        SELECT  @UserTestId,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [QuestionNumber],
                QuestionUId,
                @UserId
        FROM    AdminTestQuestion
        WHERE   AdminTestId = @AdminTestId   
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @RC = 0
        RETURN
    END CATCH 
    SET @RC = 1
    RETURN
END
```

I am calling it like this:

```
DECLARE @PurchaseDate DATETIME
DECLARE @RC     INT  
exec sp_purchase_test  119, @PurchaseDate OUT, @RC OUT, 4  
SELECT @RC
```

It's returning a "0" but I cannot see what's failing. How can I debug this to give me more information as to why it is returning a 0.

Comment: Remove the TRY/CATCH? Or just PRINT the error message?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx This is the documentation: Look at the part about looking at the content of the error.

Answer (score 2):

From the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175976.aspx), in your CATCH block you can get the details of the error that has been caught:

> **Retrieving Error Information** In the scope of a CATCH block, the following system functions can be used to obtain information about the error that caused the CATCH block to be executed:
>
> ERROR_NUMBER() returns the number of the error.
>
> ERROR_SEVERITY() returns the severity.
>
> ERROR_STATE() returns the error state number.
>
> ERROR_PROCEDURE() returns the name of the stored procedure or trigger where the error occurred.
>
> ERROR_LINE() returns the line number inside the routine that caused the error.
>
> ERROR_MESSAGE() returns the complete text of the error message. The text includes the values supplied for any substitutable parameters, such as lengths, object names, or times.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just remove the `TRY..CATCH` so you can see the problem? Make a copy if you can't modify the original. If you have no permissions even to create a copy, you should still be able to create a temporary sproc by prefixing the name with #.

In general, it's a terrible idea to have a procedure that "cannot fail" but only because it returns an unhelpful "something went wrong" value; just let the error bubble up to the caller. `TRY..CATCH` will also do nothing to ensure data integrity -- that your statements have failed doesn't mean nothing happened. To achieve that, you'll need to wrap the whole thing in a transaction, and issue a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` while you're at it to ensure it will roll back at the first sign of trouble. Obviously, all of this requires the ability to modify the client code, which you may not have.

All that said, it *is* possible to debug stored procedures. I've heard legends. I've just never been able to configure it on one of my own systems, and I'm not sure it's worth the bother. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to implement error handling in the `CATCH` portion of your `TRY-CATCH`.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @errorMessage nvarchar(4000),
        @errorNumber int,
        @errorSeverity int,
        @errorState int,
        @errorLine int,
        @errorProcedure nvarchar(128);

BEGIN TRY

    /* Your code. */

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT @errorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @errorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
           @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
           @errorState = ERROR_STATE(),
           @errorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
           @errorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE();

    /* You can ROLLBACK here, as needed. */

    RAISERROR('%s (Error %d occurred at line %d in %s.)',
              @errorSeverity,
              @errorState,
              @errorMessage,
              @errorNumber,
              @errorLine,
              @errorProcedure);

END CATCH
```